# Adding Component to default toolbar dynamically base on page load with ABP Framework 3.2

Tags: blazor-webassembly, abp

Been working with ABP 3.2 blazor and so far so good. I know how to add a new component to the default toolbar from my module, the documentation is very clear on how to do this. What I am trying to do is add a component to the toolbar when I load a specific page.
For example, If I load the Invoice page /Invoice, I want to load a specific component to the toolbar. When I switch page to let's say /Sales, I show a different component. Basically how to I add and remove toolbar items base of the page I am loading.

Thanks for any help.